# Need an effective way to show distribution changes over time and outlier reoccurence

Tags: time-series, distributions, large-data

Does anyone have suggestions on the best way to approach this problem?

I have a large dataset (over 200k+ per day) in a MySQL database, that consists of a single record per user per day with a continuous response variable. The data is highly left-skewed and outliers are of importance, so it's not sufficient to measure trends with average/sd.

The graph I'm trying to get would be a series of boxplots, with one boxplot object for each day of data. MySQL does not seem to offer any functions for pulling the quartiles and median. I could hack something together using joins but so far performance is slow and not feasible for the whole dataset.

Also of interest, would be to track the outliers each day to see if the outliers are of the same population subset, or are relatively random.

My initial strategy is to condense the data by bucketing all the records into rounded values, however I seem to lose some accuracy by doing this and I'm not sure if there is support in the plotting package I'm using (ggplot2).

Ideally, this analysis could be updated daily but it is not time-critical, and could be run in a few hours if necessary.

Technologies used: MySQL, R, ggplot2, Python